# How can I extract text slide by slide using Apache Tika (in Scala)?

Tags: scala, powerpoint, apache-tika

I'm trying to extract text from a PPT using Apache Tika.  The code below allows me to do that.

```
 val pptInputStream = new FileInputStream(pptFile)

 val autoDetectParser = new AutoDetectParser()

 val metadata = new Metadata()

 val stringWriter = new StringWriter()

 val handlerBody = new BodyContentHandler(-1)      //takes whole text (-1 == all)

 val pC = new ParseContext

 autoDetectParser.parse(pptInputStream, handlerBody, metadata, pC)

 val allSlideText = handlerWrite.toString
```

But, I'd like to have the extracted text delimited by slide.  It can be streamed in slide by slide or as a whole (the files I'm using aren't large at all), but what's important is that I can determine which text is on slide #1, which text is on slide #2, etc.

I'm thinking there may be some metadata that will help with this, but I have no experience with this kind of stuff.

Thanks in advance for any guidance.

Comment: Extract as HTML rather than plain text, then split on the `<div class="slide-content">` and `<div class="slide-notes">` entries in the HTML you get back?

Comment: Thanks, @Gagravarr!  Using the handler toXMLContentHandler() I was able to access the html and split as you suggested.  Much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Promoting a comment to an answer...

It can't be done at the plain text level, as the semantic information around pages has been thrown away by that point

What you need to do is to extract the PowerPoint file as XHTML, [examples on how to do that from Java here on the Tika website](http://tika.apache.org/1.11/examples.html#Parsing_to_XHTML). Then, once you've got that, you'll see that the HTML has a structure like:

```
<body>
<div class="slideShow">
    <div class="slide">
       <div class="slide-master-content">
       </div>
       <div class="slide-content">
       </div>
    </div>
    <div class="slide">
       <div class="slide-content">
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="slide-notes">
</div>
</body>
```

So, you'll find a div for each slide, and within that you'll be able to see what's the slide itself, and what came from the slide master (if any). Split that by slide divs, then grab the text out, and you're there!

Comment: When I have a slide-note in the first and the last slide, the slide-notes div only contains two <p> elements. Is there any way to know which slide which slide-note came from?